# Unintentional Two Master Branches Git

Tags: xcode, git

I had written some code in Xcode that I knew I wasn't going to be using, but wanted to keep in git just in case. I committed and pushed this, and then tried to undo this via

`git reset HEAD^`

I probably should have just used my tried and true method of hard resets. But now I have the following:

```
   A origin /master undoing head
     |
   origin master 1 /head 1 master messed up commit
     |
     |    GOLDEN COMMIT **I WANT TO BE HERE**
     |
     |
     |
     |
      \ 
        master (a really old commit !)
     |
     |
     |
     |
```

All I want to do is get back to the golden commit. But I have this master branch that is an old commit, and every time I pull nothing happens. What is going on !? My project is now corrupted and I can't open it

Comment: I can't make sense of your history graph. Can you make it look like in `man git-rebase`, or `git log --graph --oneline`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really** want a given commit, and don't care about losing local changes, `force` a `checkout`:

```
$ git checkout -f golden_commit
```

That will update your local files (those which were tracked at the time of commit) no matter what.

`git reset` only modifies your local repo. It does not touch what you have pushed elsewhere. Get your local repo to look like you want it first, and don't try pushing or pulling before you have that.

Once your local repo is fine, you can discard the really old master in your remote (if you don't think anyone else is using it) with `git checkout master -f && git push origin master -f`. The old master in your remote will eventually get lost.

Comment: Gauthier thanks ! This worked. For some reason there my pod file and workspace file got lost and I had to recreate those. This is an Xcode specific issue though so accepting as is